# Positional z-index for sprites

Tags: javascript, math

I have absolutely positioned objects/sprites that move around in an area of 1000px x 1000px. I want these sprites to have z-indexes relative to their position:
- the further to the left the higher the z-index.
- the further down the higher the z-index (also including the height of the object).
So objects on the bottom left of the area will have a much higher z-index than those on the top right - which should create a cool illusion when object pass close to each other.

Ive tried this but it fails:

```
object.style.zIndex = ( 1000 - parseInt(object.style.left) ) + 
                      parseInt(object.style.top) + object.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

Algorithmically:

1. Read all sprites inside an array;
2. Iterate over all array objects, read left position attribute of each, store in same array;
3. Sort array numerically by value (that is left position attribute);
4. Iterate over all arrayy objects, set z-index by array item index.

Using jQuery will make this code shorter. If you give us sample code of your sprites and that area, we can try eaven create some JS code, that "does the job"...

Comment: thanks for the offer on this - but i dont want to use an array for this cause in doing it on the fly with setInterval(?,100)

Comment: oh - and ive already built the whole mechanism without jquery. Now that im typing this, i am actually iterating thru all moving elements and storing their values - i will use the code suggested above and stash the value - ill reply with result asap...

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do use maths

Do this when ever a sprite moves so add it to the method or function thats moving them

```
spritePos = {
             'x':1000 - parseInt(object.style.top.replace("px")),
             'y':parseInt(object.style.left.replace("px")) - 1000 
}; 

zIndex = spritePos.x + spritePos.y;
object.style.zIndex = zIndex;
```

Comment: ok tried your code but it still didnt work -however it did behave when i changed it to this: 
return ((parseInt(o.style.top)+o.clientHeight)*100)+(parseInt(o.style.left)-8000)